# For loop condition issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am having troubles figuring out the for condition for a javascript learning course I am doing.

I am not getting normal errors because I am doing it in the course, but the error I am receiving in the course is this...

`Oops, try again. Careful: your second 'for' loop should stop when it reaches its current point in the string + myName.length.`

These are the instructions:

```
First, you'll want to set your second loop's iterator to start at the first one, so it picks up where that one left off. If your first loop starts with

for(var i = 0; // rest of loop setup
your second should be something like

for(var j = i; // rest of loop setup
Second, think hard about when your loop should stop. Check the Hint if you get stuck!

Finally, in the body of your loop, have your program use the .push() method of hits. Just like strings and arrays have a .length method, arrays have a .push() method that adds the thing between parentheses to the end of the array. For example,

newArray = [];
newArray.push('hello');
newArray[0];   // equals 'hello'
```

This is my code

```
var text = "Hello, my name is Becky. What is your name?\
I repeat, my name is Becky. Can't you figure out that my\
name is Becky. Becky!!!!";
var myName = "Becky";
var hits = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === 'B') {
        for (var j = i; i < myName.length; i++) {
            hits.push();
        }
    }
}
```

I know the issue resides in this line:

`for (var j = i; i < myName.length; i++) {`

I just can't figure out exactly how I need to structure it.

UPDATE:

Final answer of question:

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text = "Hello, my name is Becky. What is your name?\
I repeat, my name is Becky. Can't you figure out that my\
name is Becky. Becky!!!!";
var myName = "Becky";
var hits = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === 'B') {
        for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++) {
            hits.push(myName);
        }
    }
}
if (hits === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: The key is in this part of the comment: "... **current point in the string** + myName.length ...."

Comment: So `var j`?? Like this '; j < myName.length;' ... I have tried that and it put it into an infinite loop.

Comment: Start by analyzing the structure of a for loop: you have the initialization, the end condition, and the increment. Be certain that your increment affects the end condition.

Comment: @cale_b I have also tried `j + myName.length;`

Comment: @dsh Do you mean adding in the j variable instead?

Comment: Also note you didn't really indicate what the code is supposed to do. By looking at it I can probably figure out, but it wouldn't hurt to be explicit about what the task is.

Comment: The code is supposed to find my name from the text variable.

Comment: Here's another hint: `for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); i++) {`

Comment: ALSO: Run this code in your browser.  Drop it into an HTML file, load it in your browser, and see what's going on. Don't rely on the feedback of the instructors.

Comment: Right, well that isn't what the code is doing. You mean you need to count the number of occurrences of `myName` from `text`. I'd suggest you update your question.

Comment: @Becky Yes. You need to add to `j` when you are using `j` to control the loop.  Eg `for (var j = ... ; j < ... ; j += 1)`.  If you check `j < ...` but increment `i++`, then `j` never changes during the loop and so the loop will never end.

Comment: I think I got that part to work? But now this came up... `Oops, try again. It looks like your second 'for' loop isn't pushing values to the hits array. Make sure it's working properly and that myName's text appears somewhere in the text variable.` Which is still part of the second for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the solution because you can learn more from the direct solution than from banging your head on that one.

```
var text = "Hello, my name is Becky. What is your name?\
I repeat, my name is Becky. Can't you figure out that my\
name is Becky. Becky!!!!";
var myName = "Becky";
var hits = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == 'B') {
        var equal = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < myName.length; j++) {
            if (text[i + j] != myName[j]) {
                equal = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if(equal) hits.push(myName);
    }
}
```

There may be other ways to reach this result. This is one of them.

**Explaing what "push" does:**

Arrays are lists of variables. You store a value in a variable like this:

```
var myNumber = 777;
var myName = "Nelson";
```

An array declaration looks like this:

```
var myNumbers = [];
```

then you put something inside of it, like this:

```
myNumbers.push(333);
myNumbers.push(555);
myNumbers.push(777);
```

then if you try: `console.log(myNumbers)`, it will print: [333, 555, 777]

if you add another push:

```
myNumbers.push(999);
```

will add 999 to the list resulting in  `[333, 555, 777, 999]`

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3cv12y4/)

got it ? take a look here to more detailed explanation:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Comment: It is making me use the push method.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, but I will go over the lesson again. Thanks!

Comment: you can ask more if you want... i'll try to help

Comment: Well, I had to do it a certain way due to the website - Codeacademy. I had my name four times, but it printed out 16 times and the site said it was correct. I just really don't understand the second for loop and the hits part. This code `for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++) {
            hits.push(myName);`.

Comment: this code in your comment is what the site said was correct ?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention in my post that I edited my question with the code that the site said was correct.

Comment: Well... AFAIU, this answer is simply wrong. The 2nd loop function should be check if all characters in myName are present in that main string position. In their answer they are populating the final result WHILE checking, when the correct would be populate the result after the check finishes. And the result is obviously wrong. In your place I would contact their support and check if this is really correct. Now, did you understand the code in my answer and in @phpsmashcode answer ?

Comment: Also, please include in your question the complete instructions of the problem.

Comment: No, I don't understand it. I don't really understand `push` yet. This was the first occurrence of it. The text in my question, was the complete question for this problem. It goes in steps and there were several questions before it, but I was correct on all of them. The question after this current one just had me put the if statement after the second for loop.

Comment: Included an explantion about push in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure what you are trying to achieve,

Here is something may help

```
var text = "Hello, my name is Becky. What is your name?\
I repeat, my name is Becky. Can't you figure out that my\
name is Becky. Becky!!!!";
var myName = "Becky";
var hits = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == 'B') {
        var res = '';
        for (var j = i; j < i+myName.length; j++) {
            res = res+text[j];
        }
        if(res == myName)
        {
            hits.push(myName);
        }
    }
}
console.log(hits);
```

Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g9boknu3/)